# Why not use sudo instead of setuid/setgid?

Tags: privilege-escalation, sudo

If it is an insecure practise to use setuid/setgid binaries, why do distributions, OSes force it?

**The big question**: what prevents using sudo instead of the setuid/setgid binaries?

"ping" would be enough for root, no? If a user wants it, give it sudo permission?

Comment: So you are suggesting to use a single setuid binary (sudo) instead of using multiple setuid binaries? What about `passwd` (tool for changing the users password) which is also setuid?

Comment: Do you realize that `sudo` is itself a setuid binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your suggestion doesn't reduce the attack surface at all. In fact, it increases it. With programs like `ping` being setuid, it would take a vulnerability in `ping` itself to exploit it. If the file itself weren't setuid, and users instead had permission to use it via `sudo`, then either a vulnerability in `ping` or one in `sudo` would do. And even if the system has `sudo` anyway, most of the security bugs that have been found in it over the years have been ways for a user with some sort of permission to use `sudo` to instead gain full root. Bugs that a user with no `sudo` access at all can exploit are essentially unheard of.